# Limiting scope of JavaScript source

Tags: javascript

I have temporarily taken over a basic web project from my work colleague who has gone on honeymoon. It's using the Kentico platform. I'm quite inexperienced with web development; I know enough to get by for the majority of the project, but I've come across an issue. There is a script that needs to be run on one table in the webpage that relies on:

```
<script   
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

However, adding this source screws with the rest of the webpage and renders it unusable.

Is there a way to "limit the scope" of the source so that it doesn't affect the entire webpage?

Comment: 1) Java script files apply to the entire page 2) table transforms are done via selector. So we need to know what selector is being used to change the table. That code is need 3) This is a really really old version of jquery. You should consider patching it.

Comment: To get useful advise on how to fix this, you'll need to show us the "rest of the webpage" and how it is broken.

Comment: Telling by their webpage, Kentico uses jQuery 1.8.3. You want to aditionally include the even older version 1.6.4? What happens if you just remove that line, loading jQuery 1.6.4? Any JS errors? If that's the case, either your script is executed before Kentico loaded its version of jquery or your script uses some deprecated functions and should be updated soon. Just to give you a perspective, the current stable version of jQuery is 3.1.1. [Version 1.6.4 has been released in Sep 2011](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/releases/tag/1.6.4)

Comment: Thanks guys. I was told we needed to run this version of jQuery for the script to work. But I just tried it with the Kentico version and it seems to be running without an issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery has a specific function, [`$.noConflict()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/), that does exactly this.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    altjquery = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

Now your newly loaded jQuery has been pulled from the default `$` and `jQuery` (now accessed from `altjquery` instead) and the original values recovered.

If you want to use your version of jQuery within your own code, you might follow this up with something like:

```
(function($){
    // Your code here
})(altjquery);
```

This would enable you to use the typical `$` for your jQuery within that section.

You may want to reconsider though. Your page already has jQuery loaded (which is why you're having this problem). Even worse, you're trying to load an older version. You're likely to be better off either using the page's jQuery or loading a newer version.

Comment: Thanks heaps! We needed to run some super old script that "apparently" needed this exact version of jQuery running. However, I tried just running the script with the version the page is already running and everything seems to be working fine. Thanks for the heads up about noConflict() though, will definitely remember it for future use!

Comment: I'm trying the same by using Bootstrap only locally. I followed the example [Bootstrap Collapse on w3](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp) but it messed up the other content in my page. This is just an example where limitation could be useful. I would like to know how to limit its scope to make use of it in a possible upcoming case in our production environment. `function($)` can not be applied here as this example does not use a distinctive function.

Comment: @Stefan That sounds like the sort of thing you should ask as a separate question rather than bumping an answer that's a couple years old. If nothing else, you'd certainly get more attention on your question and that would make it a lot more likely that you'd get an answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue you are having is more about the jQuery selectors than the scope. You will need to narrow down the $() calls in the existing code to the table you are interested.

For example you can use `$('#myTable')` instead of `$('table')`

Comment: I doubt if this is the problem.